# plotting a graph in Excel and Visual Studio

Tags: c++

What is the tool that I must enable to plot a graph or chart using Microsoft Excel in Visual Studio as I heard that there is a tool which will plot a graph based on the code created

help please

Answer (score 0):

Are you using VS 2012 or 13?. If so install SPreadSheetGear 2012. It is an extension for visual studio which enables you to leverage excel reporting.

Another option is to use CMMI of microsoft. Here is a link. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee461589(v=vs.110).aspx

Hope that helps 
Let me know

Comment: VS 2012, is there any tool to enable inside VS to plot an excel graph??

Comment: Not to my knowledge. I have used Microsoft office drivers for visual studio to accomplish a similar task before.